Extraer datos del ROOT de XML de SAT en Python
Estoy tratando de extraer datos de la etiqueta ROOT sin embargo no encuentro como hacerlo, este es la parte del XML
Los datos que trato de sacar son Total, Subtotal, Moneda
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4.0" Serie="E" Folio="962571" Fecha="2024-01-12T13:22:05" Sello="aUyelKnB5ppFaeumiZPIjFDd+mFna5OT2dGL4GLsjSh991eRascyuaoDEAsDRafr+5EXPWm70XS+wuVvwk81Af5NYRRaC8ejQ==" FormaPago="99" NoCertificado="00001000000123456789" Certificado="sakjnarwjwniA" CondicionesDePago="01/01/2024 01:22:05 PM" SubTotal="2988.00" Descuento="0.00" Moneda="MXN" Total="7183.30" TipoDeComprobante="I" Exportacion="01" MetodoPago="DEP" LugarExpedicion="333" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="DUMMY12345" Nombre="DUMMY SERVICE" RegimenFiscal="601"/>

He utilizado
from lxml import etree as ET
root = d.getroot()
print(root)


<Element {http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4}Comprobante at 0x1d2be714280>

Aparece eso, y si lo itero si puedo ver los hijos, sin embargo no puedo ver los datos que se encuentran en el ROOT
Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme a ver como los puedo leer.

Los datos que quieres obtener son atributos, los puedes obtener usando el método get() de cualquier elemento:
from lxml import etree as ET


root = ET.XML(b"""\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="4.0" Serie="E" Folio="962571" Fecha="2024-01-12T13:22:05" Sello="aUyelKnB5ppFaeumiZPIjFDd+mFna5OT2dGL4GLsjSh991eRascyuaoDEAsDRafr+5EXPWm70XS+wuVvwk81Af5NYRRaC8ejQ==" FormaPago="99" NoCertificado="00001000000123456789" Certificado="sakjnarwjwniA" CondicionesDePago="01/01/2024 01:22:05 PM" SubTotal="2988.00" Descuento="0.00" Moneda="MXN" Total="7183.30" TipoDeComprobante="I" Exportacion="01" MetodoPago="DEP" LugarExpedicion="333" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd">
   <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="DUMMY12345" Nombre="DUMMY SERVICE" RegimenFiscal="601" />
</cfdi:Comprobante>
""")

total = root.get("Total")
subtotal = root.get("SubTotal")
moneda = root.get("Moneda")

print(f"Total: {total}\nSubtotal: {subtotal}\nMoneda: {moneda}")

Salida
Total: 7183.30
Subtotal: 2988.00
Moneda: MXN


Si necesitaras iterar sobre todos los atributos o listarlos todos, puedes hacer uso del método items():
for attr, val in root.items():
    print(f"{attr}: {val}")

Salida
Version: 4.0
Serie: E
Folio: 962571
Fecha: 2024-01-12T13:22:05
Sello: aUyelKnB5ppFaeumiZPIjFDd+mFna5OT2dGL4GLsjSh991eRascyuaoDEAsDRafr+5EXPWm70XS+wuVvwk81Af5NYRRaC8ejQ==
FormaPago: 99
NoCertificado: 00001000000123456789
Certificado: sakjnarwjwniA
CondicionesDePago: 01/01/2024 01:22:05 PM
SubTotal: 2988.00
Descuento: 0.00
Moneda: MXN
Total: 7183.30
TipoDeComprobante: I
Exportacion: 01
MetodoPago: DEP
LugarExpedicion: 333
{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation: http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd


Muchas gracias amigo, lo intente mucho rato y no encontraba como hacerlo, pero tienes razón
Mi codigo final quedo asi:
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
from lxml import etree as ET 

d = ET.parse("78173 E.xml")
root = d.getroot()
print(root)

Total = root.get("Total")
Moneda = root.get("Moneda")
Subtotal = root.get("Subtotal")

print("Total: " + str(total))
print("Subtotal: " + str(Subtotal))
print("Moneda: " + Moneda)

Total: 7183.30
Subtotal: 2988.00
Moneda: MXN
